# IE thinking object isn't loaded

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I've got code that's something like the following:

```
<script src="library.js"></script><!-- loads window.lib and lib.subLib -->
<script>
if (!window.lib) { alert("foo") }; //Triggers, despite library.js being loaded fine
lib.custLib = function(b) { ... }(lib.subLib); //Works fine, even though IE JUST said that window.lib wasn't loaded
</script>
```

And just to make things crazier, after the page is loaded, if I type

```
javascript:if(window.lib)alert("foo");
```

into the location bar, the alert fires, indicating window.lib is loaded. If instead I type

```
javascript:if(!window.lib)alert("foo");
```

the alert does NOT fire, confirming that !window.lib doesn't evaluate to true.

The only conclusion I can come to is that somehow library.js is completing execution something between when I first check if window.lib exists and when I actually use lib.subLib in the immediate invocation right after the function declaration.

EDIT: Additional information...

I've found a workaround, but first, some interesting things to note.

```
<script src="library.js"></script><!-- loads window.lib and lib.subLib -->
<script>
alert(!window.lib) //True
if (!window.lib) {
  alert(!window.lib) //True
}
</script>
```

Compare to:

```
<script src="library.js"></script><!-- loads window.lib and lib.subLib -->
<script>
alert(!window.lib) //False
</script>
<script>
if (!window.lib) {
  alert(!window.lib) //True
}
</script>
```

And the workaround:

```
<script src="library.js"></script><!-- loads window.lib and lib.subLib -->
<script>
var foo = !window.lib;
</script>
<script>
if (foo) {
  alert(!window.lib) //Doesn't get triggered
}
</script>
```

So in summation, this appears to be a bug in Internet Explorer. The workaround is to have a separate script block that set a variable to the value of !window.lib, and then to check that variable in the next script block, rather than checking !window.lib directly.

Comment: What *is* this `lib`? Where and how is it declared and assigned? Without code, all we can do is guess.

Comment: If it matters, then that may answer my question. My understanding is that library.js should be completely finished before the next bit of script is run, even though library.js is an external file and the following script is inline. Is that not the case? Are they run in parallel, or is it otherwise possible for the inline script to run before all the code in library.js has finished execution?

Comment: that's not what I asked. I think the problem is inside that external script. For example maybe it initialize that `lib` in timer or only after page load.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard, neither of those is the case. The script is an internal one written by the guy in the next cube, whose code I am quite familiar with, and which does not defer execution of any components in any manner.